# Integrating GeoDjango into existing Django project

Tags: database, django, geodjango

I have a Django project with multiple apps. They all share a db with `engine = django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2`. Now I want some functionality of `GeoDjango` and decided I want to integrate it into my existing project. I read through the tutorial, and it looks like I have to create a separate spartial database for GeoDjango. I wonder if there is anyway around. I tried to add this into one of my apps' models.py without changing my db settings :

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField

class Location(models.Model):
        location = PointField()
```

But when I run syncdb, I got this error.

```
File "/home/virtual/virtual-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 200, in db_type
    return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self)
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, as i recall, django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis is extension of postgresql_psycopg2 so you could change db driver in settings, create new db with spatial template and then migrate data to new db (South is great for this). By itself geodjango is highly dependent on DB inner methods thus, unfortunately, you couldn't use it with regular db.

Other way - you could make use of django's [multi-db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/) ability, and create extra db for geodjango models.

Comment: If you aren't using South, you need to start. Especially if you develop with version control tools.

Answer (score 1):

Your error looks like it comes from not changing the database extension in your settings file. You don't technically need to create a new database using the spatial template, you can simply run the PostGIS scripts on your existing database to get all of the geospatial goodies. As always, you should backup your existing database before doing this though.

Comment: how to run the POSTGIS script on the existing databse please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100%, but I think that you can pipe postgis.sql and spatial_ref_sys.sql into your existing database, grant permissions to the tables, and change the db setting to "django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis". (After you have installed the deps of course)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#spatialdb-template

I'd be interested to see what you find.  Be careful, postgis installation can build some character but you don't want it to build too much.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs (django 3.1) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#migration-operation-for-adding-extensions :

> If you need to add a PostgreSQL extension (like hstore, postgis, etc.) using a migration, use the CreateExtension operation.